# Playing an MP3 throughout entire rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, mp3

I want to show an MP3 player that the user can control while navigating the rails app. When they load new pages, the MP3 will continue playing. My first thought was to make every page load with AJAX, and have the MP3 player on the main page. So new content loads, but the MP3 player just stays in place.

Second thoughts: I would need to 'ajaxify' the whole rails app just to show the mp3 player. In addition, I suspect this is less search-engine friendly than a normal app.  I would appreciate your opinions and options on this matter.  Or isn't the SEO thing a problem? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the changing url in JavaScript and modify the page content dynamically without actually reloading the page. A popular library function that handles this is [Angular's routing capabilities.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$route)